# Sort datatable on occurrence of string

Tags: c#, linq

I want to sort a data table on base of occurrence of string like that.

```
1."aaa";
2."aaa";
3."aaa";
4."asaa";
5."asaa";
6."ccc";
```

So my table will be sorted in maximum occurred order of string.

```
1."aaa";
2."aaa";
3."aaa";
4."asaa";
5."asaa";
6."ccc";
```

How to do this. **Preferably using LINQ query**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var strings = new[] { "ccc", "asaa", "asaa", "aaa", "aaa", "aaa" };
var sortedStrings = strings
  .GroupBy(s => s)
  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
  .SelectMany(g => g);
```